# Do I need to restore a site to fix a User Information List issue?

Tags: sharepoint-server, user-profile

I'm a SharePoint admin and I was cleaning up orphaned users and I've broken a custom solution. I didn't know it was looking up the UIL user list IDs in order to allow custom webparts to display who owned what - it's a project management solution.

The solution owner needs the users, who are no longer in AD, adding back to the UIL with their original list IDs and suggested I restore the site. This is beyond my knowledge and I don't know if that will work.

Any h..e..l..p...\o/....

Comment: Lesson: Don't mess with the user info list.

Comment: "Cleaning up orphaned users" is not a thing. Just ask your compliance officer. The user list is important for user history and accountability.

Answer (score 1):

If the user object in AD no longer exists, you cannot add it back to the UIL nor can you add a new object with a specific ID; all new objects will increment the ID value.

The only way you can get back to the original state is to [perform an unsupported operation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/841057/) on the UserInfo table of the Content Database (that is, update tp_Deleted = 1 to 0 on the row containing the now deleted user).

You could restore the Site Collection (or Content Database) from backup, as well.

I would suggest instead fixing the application...

Have your domain admins checked to see if the AD User object is still in the AD recycle bin (if enabled)? That can be restored, enabled, then you can just re-add that person to the UIL.

Comment: Thanks. If we can restore at list level from a backup, is the UIL something that can be restored? And.. am I correct in saying a restored list will have the original list IDs?

Comment: I don't know that restoring the UIL is supported. It isn't the same as a standard list as it doesn't feed from `dbo.AllUserData`. If you go down that path, I'd strongly recommend taking a content database backup first.